# bower.json and package.json interpolation

Tags: json, angularjs, npm, bower, brunch

I got a project from 3rd party and they have something like below in bower.json and package.json file

```
"name": "${project.artifactId}",
"description": "${project.description}",
"version": "${project.version}",
```

I cannot figure out which build engine uses `${}` interpolation in .json file. There is also `brunch-config.cofee` file with similar usage. I don't see anything describing those variables. My `brunch build` just fail completely (maybe for unrelated reason):

```
$ brunch build -d
14 Aug 23:03:50 - error: { [Error: Component must have "/Users/test/bower/angular/bower.json"] code: 'NO_BOWER_JSON' }
  brunch:watch Loaded plugins:  +0ms
  brunch:watch File 'package.json' received event 'add' +11ms
  brunch:watch File 'bower.json' received event 'add' +2ms
  brunch:watch File 'brunch-config.coffee' received event 'add' +0ms
```

Can you help to provide some guidance?

Thanks

Comment: Probably they used [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html). It looks like the [Maven Model Interpolation](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/maven-model-builder/#Model_Interpolation). Look at the [configuration docs](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) to see where these configurations reside

Comment: Please post answer below and I will approve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably they used [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html). It looks like the [Maven Model Interpolation](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/maven-model-builder/#Model_Interpolation). Look at the [configuration docs](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) to see where these configurations reside